# Oracle - Inline View - External WHERE condition applied inline

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a table where dates are stored as VARCHAR2(*It's legacy data table which we have no control on!*) in format of YYYYMMDD. We have only SELECT privilege on table (*Not feasible to write procedure/functions*).

Need to select all rows from table where date is > sysdate.

We apply regular expression check for valid format and additional checks to ensure that day is valid for given month. All this works great! Our inline view selection ensures that only records with valid date strings are picked.

But, when we apply condition to check > sysdate as an external clause - we get invalid date for given month error even though inline view selection ensures that no such records are picked.

It looks like query execution is applying the condition from outer clause before inline view conditions are applied. Appreciate any comments on the behavior; and, how can we ensure that conditions from outside are applied only once inline conditions are met?

Data and Used Queries:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA_TABLE
(
  DATESTRING  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
);
```

Insert 3 rows with values:

```
19960322 --Valid Date in past
19831131 --Invalid Date 11/31
20180224 --Valid Date > SYSDATE
```

Valid data selection:
(Where clause 1 ensures format and clause 2 ensures valid date for month):

```
SELECT datestring AS i_dob
  FROM test_data_table
 WHERE     REGEXP_LIKE (TRIM (datestring),
                        '(19|20)\d\d(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])')
       AND TRIM (datestring) <=
              TO_CHAR (
                 LAST_DAY (
                    TO_DATE (SUBSTR (TRIM (datestring), 1, 6) || '01',
                             'YYYYMMDD')),
                 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Above query works fine and return valid rows with valid date string,

To select records having date string > SYSDATE, above data is used inline and we apply condition >SYSDATE as below.

```
SELECT i_dob
  FROM (
    SELECT datestring AS i_dob
      FROM test_data_table
     WHERE     REGEXP_LIKE (TRIM (datestring),
                            '(19|20)\d\d(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])')
           AND TRIM (datestring) <=
                  TO_CHAR (
                     LAST_DAY (
                        TO_DATE (SUBSTR (TRIM (datestring), 1, 6) || '01',
                                 'YYYYMMDD')),
                     'YYYYMMDD')
) X
 WHERE TO_DATE (X.I_DOB, 'YYYYMMDD') > SYSDATE
```

It starts throwing error: `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified`

Looks like the conditions are applied before all inline view conditions are checked.

Comment: OK, this is an interesting question - thanks for posting it! Two observations so far (I will keep looking...) **FIRST**: instead of the `WHERE` clause as you have it, you could check for `X.I_DOB > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')`. Of course, this doesn't answer your question (and perhaps you need the date for other computations, where you really need to convert it to a date); just pointing out that for this specific query there's a workaround.

Comment: **SECOND** Looking into hints; I thought `/*+ ORDERED_PREDICATES */` should work, and indeed it does if you combine the two WHERE clauses into one (no subquery), but with the subquery - outer query structure it does not. I'll write back if I can figure out the correct hint for this (I thought `NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION` should work but it doesn't or I didn't use it correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by making the inline view be actioned before the outer query by adding an additional rownum column to it (the presence of the rownum column means that Oracle needs to calculate that column for the subquery it applies to before it can further filter on it.

So, your query would become:

```
SELECT i_dob
  FROM (
    SELECT datestring AS i_dob,
           rownum rn
      FROM test_data_table
     WHERE     REGEXP_LIKE (TRIM (datestring),
                            '(19|20)\d\d(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])')
           AND TRIM (datestring) <=
                  TO_CHAR (
                     LAST_DAY (
                        TO_DATE (SUBSTR (TRIM (datestring), 1, 6) || '01',
                                 'YYYYMMDD')),
                     'YYYYMMDD')
) X
 WHERE TO_DATE (X.I_DOB, 'YYYYMMDD') > SYSDATE;
```

I would add a comment into your query explaining the presence of this column, otherwise some developer in the future may think "eh? This does nothing; I'll remove it!".

(Also of note is in 12.2, they have added/amended functions to allow for [easier data validation](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/entry/simplifying_your_data_validation_code), which would simplify your query when you get to 12.2!)

Comment: What's that gonna do to the performance? While the workaround works functionally, it's hack on top of hack.... :(

Comment: Agree on performance hit, but looks like there is no other option..Query optimizer might be ordering based on performance, but we are forcing the order of execution.

Comment: It's possible you could get some benefit from using one of the following hints instead of the rownum "trick": no_merge, no_unnest, no_push_pred. Unfortunately I don't have the time to check the validity of these hints for this scenario.

Comment: After reading through docs, I expected NO_MERGE and NO_PUSH_PRED to work. Unfortunately it did not. I introduced hints "SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE(X) NO_PUSH_PRED(X) */ i_dob" and got the same error.

Comment: <rant>My point is, why not just fix the table and use the correct datatype. I know, I know, you have no control. But someone does. Eventually these hacks will come back and bite you. I have lost count the number of times I have seen this. Anyway, it's just my advice, which is worth exactly what you paid for it :)  <end rant>

Comment: @mathguy Second condition in inner WHERE ensures that it will not allow date greater than max date in a month:   AND TRIM (datestring) <=
                  TO_CHAR (
                     LAST_DAY (
                        TO_DATE (SUBSTR (TRIM (datestring), 1, 6) || '01',
                                 'YYYYMMDD')),
                     'YYYYMMDD')

Comment: I realized that and deleted my comment! :-)

Comment: @BobC - the performance hit should be minimal; `rownum` is generated anyway, and simply including it in the subquery doesn't cause much disturbance.

Comment: @mathguy. I know that rownum is generated; but what I meant was that since we have apply a predicate to rownum, we might be forcing the the plan to be a non-mergable view, which in turn could prevent certain optimizations from being available to the optimizer. Of course it may not apply here. It's just a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: @BobC - err... merging is exactly what needs to be prevented here! Strangely, `/*+ NO_MERGE */`  doesn't work - that would be the best option. This example is proving that I don't understand hints as well as I thought I did.

Comment: @mathguy. But thats my point. We are having to coerce the optimizer into doing things (or not doing things). If we had use the right datatype in the first place, we would not be going through these hoops.